# How to keep a MainActivity running when an Intent is called?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

i have an code that when I call the map activity it receives the Latitude and Longitude and shows on the map, but when I am on the map the `onLocationChange`does not run, so it doesn't show the place when the person is moving only the first atributtes, how do i change that to make it send the atributtes constantly?

```
import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {

    private LocationManager locManager; //Gerente de Localização
    private LocationProvider locProvider; //Provedor de Localização
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2; //Utilizado nas requisições de localização
    Intent map;
    LatLng Local;

    //Inicializado aqui para não dar crash caso o mapa seja chamado antes desses atributos serem inicializados.
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    //Pacote onde será armazenado o valor do LatLng.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instância dos buttons:
        Button map = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_map);
        map.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button gnss = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_gnss);
        gnss.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button config = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_config);
        config.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button credits = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_credits);
        credits.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Fim Instância dos Buttons

        //O Gerente recebe uma location
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_map:
                Local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                //Pacote inicializado com o LatLng
                args.putParcelable("Latlng", Local);

                //Criar tela relativa ao mapa
                map = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                //O pacote é passado para a Intent referente ao mapa
                map.putExtra("bundle", args);
                startActivity(map);

                break;

            case R.id.button_gnss:
               /*Intent gnss = new Intent(this, GnssActivity.class);
                startActivity(gnss);
                */
                break;

            case R.id.button_config:
                Intent config = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(config);

                break;

            case R.id.button_credits:
                Intent credits = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
                startActivity(credits);
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // A permissão foi dada
            ativaGPS();
        }
        else {
            // Solicite a permissão
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        desativaGPS();
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            if(grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // O usuário acabou de dar a permissão
                ativaGPS();
            }
            else {
                // O usuário não deu a permissão solicitada
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sua localização não será mostrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
            }
        }
    }

    //Ativa o GPS
    public void ativaGPS() {
        try {
            locProvider = locManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(locProvider.getName(), 30000, 1, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Desativa o GPS
    public void desativaGPS() {
        try {
            locManager.removeUpdates(this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        // Alguma mudança no sistema GPS
       // A aplicação deverá chamar o método da classe LocationManager para obter   informações sobre o status do distema GPS.
        TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);
        String satInfo="PRN;Azimute;Elevação;SNR;Used in Fix\n";

        try {
            GpsStatus gpsStatus=locManager.getGpsStatus(null);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    GpsStatus gpsStatus = locManager.getGpsStatus(null);
                    Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats=gpsStatus.getSatellites();
                     for (GpsSatellite sat:sats) {
                        // processe as informações de cada satélite
                     }
                }
        // Informações do sistema estão encapsuladas no objeto gpsStatus

        // Alguma mudança no sistema GPS

        // Informações do sistema estão encapsuladas no objeto gpsStatus


    }





    //Métodos criados automaticamente na implementação do Location Listener !
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);

        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();

        //Cordenadas em DD
        coords.setText("Latitude"+latitude +"\n"+"Longitude:"+longitude);

        /*coords.setText("Latitude:"+Location.convert(latitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)
                +"\n" +
                "Longitude:"+Location.convert(longitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)); */



        //Passar o Bundle referente ao LatLng criado anteriormente.


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
    // FIM dos Métodos criados automaticamente na implementação do Location Listener !

}
```

-------------------------------------MAP ACTIVITY-------------------------------

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");

        LatLng objLatLng = bundle.getParcelable("Latlng");
        latitude = objLatLng.latitude;
        longitude= objLatLng.longitude;


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Posição atual marcada no mapa referentes a marcação e setagem da posição atual na API do Google Maps
        LatLng posAtual = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posAtual).title("Sua posição atual!"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(posAtual));

        //This goes up to 21
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posAtual, zoomLevel));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of implementing the MapActivity as a fragment which covers your MainActivity and which you can make Visible on demand?

You can then implement a method in you MapActivity which you call from onLocationChanged() and which makes all the necessary things to show the current position on the fragment.

Take a look at [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Inside your MapActivity you can then declare something like

```
public void locationChanged(double latitude, double longtitude){
     this.latitude = latitude;
     this.longtitude = longtitude
     //All necessary code you need to update the location shown on the map
}
```

In MainActivity you declare

```
public class MapFragment extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {
      private MapFragment mapFragment; 

      ...
}
```

In your onCreate() method you set the View of the Fragment

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
}
```

When you did all of that you can call the method you declared in MapFragment in your onLocationChanged() method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);

        mapFragment.locationChanged(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude();

        //Rest of your code as necessary

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can run two activity at once and even more. All you have to do is run them in background and you can use **Service** chack out the documentation at

> [android service documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

althoug not simultaneously but you can let the activities listen with the service also, you can try to start an intent for result and receive the result in the

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { /** you receive the result here**/}
```

receiveing the intent in on activity result is efficient as most voice search app, barcode scanner and map use this method